# I'm working in scheme language project and I got stuck with error in my code

Tags: lambda, scheme, racket

I'm working on a project in Scheme language and I'm stuck on an error in my code. The problem is that when i run the code for `(vide 4 '(2 3 1 5 5 2))` it gives me `(2 (2 3 1 0 6 3))` instead of the correct answer `(3 (2 3 1 0 6 3))` the problem is with the first part only.

Example of the fonction vide:

```
(vide 4 '(2 3 1 5 5 2)) ;-> (3 (2 3 1 0 6 3))
(vide 6 '(2 3 1 5 5 2)) ;-> (2 (2 3 1 5 5 0))
(vide 3 '(2 3 1 5 5 2)) ;-> (0 (2 3 0 6 5 2))


(define distribue
  (lambda (n l)
    (if (or (= n 0) (null? l))
        (list n l)
        (let ((r (distribue (- n 1) (cdr l))))
          (list (car r) (cons (+ 1 (car l))(cadr r)))))))

(distribue 5 '(2 3 1 5 5 2)) ;-> (0 (3 4 2 6 6 2))
(distribue 5 '(2 3 1)) ;-> (2 (3 4 2))

(define vide
  (lambda (n l)
    (if (null? l)
        (list n l)
      (let ((r (distribue (car l) (cdr l))))  
        (if (= n 1)
            (list  (car r)  (cons 0 (cadr r)))
            (list (+ (car l) (car r)) (cons (car l)(cadr (vide (- n 1) (cdr l))))))))))

(vide 4 '(2 3 1 5 5 2))
```

Comment: What in the world is `vide` supposed to return, in general? I can't make head or tails of your examples.

Comment: Vide means empty in English
for example 
(vide 4 '(2 3 1 5 5 2)) ;-> (3 (2 3 1 0 6 3))
what happend here that we took the forth case on the list and make empty 90

Comment: That doesn't help at all. What is it supposed to return?

Comment: What do you mean by "90"? What does the first 3 in the result mean? Why did the 5 and 2 in the input change to 6 and 3 in the output?

Comment: Vide means empty in English
for example 
(vide 4 '(2 3 1 5 5 2)) ;-> (3 (2 3 1 0 6 3))
what happend here that we took the forth case on the list and make empty (0) and then took the number in case four and we add on 1 to each element after the forth case (cuz forth case was chosen in the example)
and the rest which was 3 we listed it with the new list.
forth case in this example was 5 so we add 1 to the fifth and last case so the new list is (2 3 1 0 6 3) and the rest of 5 is 3 because we only use 2 for two cases.

Comment: for this example (vide 4 '(2 3 1 5 5 2)) it supposed to return (3 (2 3 1 0 6 3))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that in the last line, the term `(+ (car l) (car r))` is entirely incorrect; `(car l)` is the first element of the input list, which might not affect the output at all; while `r` shouldn't even matter if `n` is not equal to 1. Instead, that term should be the left-overs from the recursive call to `vide`, i.e. `(car (vide (- n 1) (cdr l)))`. Since you also use the `cadr`, I bound the recursive call in a `let` to avoid calling it twice. In addition, I put the binding of `r` to the result of `distribue` inside the `(if (= n 1) ...)` because it isn't used in the else clause now.

Here is the corrected implementation (`distribue` is left unchanged):

```
(define vide
  (lambda (n l)
    (if (null? l)
        (list n l)
        (if (= n 1)
            (let ((r (distribue (car l) (cdr l))))
              (list (car r) (cons 0 (cadr r))))
            (let ((v (vide (- n 1) (cdr l))))
              (list (car v) (cons (car l) (cadr v))))))))
```

---

As a side note to anyone else who comes by this question, I believe the rule implemented by `vide` here is akin to a single part of a move in the game [Kalah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalah), known as Mancala in the US.

Comment: Thanks for ur help and yes this rule is for Kalah game